# Ubuntu 20.04 name user add problem Bug #1927078

Tags: ldap, useradd

A problem occurred while upgrading the version of the Ubuntu system from 18.04 to 20.04.

18.04 user name For example, the user who was using 9128323 cannot log in in 20.04. (GUI only)

9128323 is a company personal number and is created according to company policy.

Due to Bug #1927078, it is impossible to create a number user, but if the badname option is used, I think that new users can use it.

Existing users are shared with open ldap, is there any way for existing users to use the GUI?

And is there a workaround to use and maintain numeric users in 20.04 by lowering the version of only some packages such as systemd, shadow, and passwd?

Comment: If you upgrade to 22.04 is the bug still there?

Comment: Both 20.04 and 22.04 are the same.

It is written that the patch has been applied since 20.04.3, but it is impossible to use and create numeric users in the GUI in the same way for both 20.04.1 and 20.04.2.